# How to completely fill holes to an image using the skimage?

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, scikit-image

I am using skimage to fill holes a binary input image (left side). This is my code

[image]

```
from skimage import ndimage
img_fill_holes=ndimage.binary_fill_holes(binary).astype(int)
```

However, the result of the above code cannot completely fill holes to the binary image. It means the output still remains the holes inside the circle. How can I completely fill all holes inside the circle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you were probably tried to apply `binary_fill_holes` on an RGB image (a 3D matrix, do `binary.shape[2] == 3` to check that).

try:

```
img_fill_holes = ndimage.binary_fill_holes(binary[:,:,0]).astype(int)
```

or any other "rgb2gray" approach and you should get the expected output

Comment: I have an array which is (301, 512,512) ,can i perform a similar operation on my array?

Comment: I just tried this and there doesn't seem to be a `ndimage` subpackage in `skimage`.   I tried importing `skimage.ndimage` and it said there was no such package.  I did however find it in SciPy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes.html and the inputs and outputs are the same.

Comment: this will ony slice the first rows of the 3d array ,please explain how to process the whole 3d nparry

Answer (score 0):

if you have the 3D array, just change the `structure` to a 3d array.

for example:
[image]

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
from scipy import ndimage
brain_mask_raw = sitk.ReadImage('/PATH/TO/brain_mask.nii.gz')
brain_mask_array = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(brain_mask_raw)
brain_mask_array_filled = ndimage.binary_fill_holes(brain_mask_array, structure=np.ones((3,3,3))).astype(int)
brain_mask_filled = sitk.GetImageFromArray(brain_mask_array_filled.astype(brain_mask_array.dtype)).CopyInformation(brain_mask_raw)
sitk.WriteImage(brain_mask_filled, '/RESULT/PATH/brain_mask_filled.nii.gz')
```

[image]

ref:[scipy doc for binary fill holes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_fill_holes.html)